# Why doesn't overriding a class function work sometimes?

Tags: javascript, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

I followed this https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions/StepByStepTutorial for Overwriting a function.

For example, I want to override the function [`_setupKeyboard()`](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/5d1c241f53863a818f8631106a25c3d9942efbe5/js/ui/keyboard.js#L1305-L1367) on the [`Keyboard`](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/5d1c241f53863a818f8631106a25c3d9942efbe5/js/ui/keyboard.js#L1214) class, but my override isn't invoked. The specific portion I want to change is this, to remove the `if` guard:

```js
if (Meta.is_wayland_compositor()) {
    this._connectSignal(this._keyboardController, 'emoji-visible',
        this._onEmojiKeyVisible.bind(this));
}
```

I copied the function from the source, removed the part I didn't want, then set the replacement function like this:

```js
const Keyboard = imports.ui.keyboard;

Keyboard.Keyboard.prototype._setupKeyboard = myOverride;
```

Why isn't my override being invoked and how can I achieve this?

Comment: How have you confirmed your function is not being called? I see two versions of this function; one in `workspace.js` and one in `workspaceThumbnail.js`. Are you sure you're overriding the correct function?

Comment: That function is called during `_init()` in GNOME Shell's initialization, so I don't see what overriding it will do. Can you post a code example of what you're actually doing so I can compose an answer to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common reasons an override won't be invoked. If the method is invoked before your override is applied, or if the function is a callback set with [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) which creates a new closure.

In this case, the function `_setupKeyboard()` is called before your override is applied. When GNOME Shell starts up, it creates an instance of `Keyboard.KeyboardManager` [here](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/5d1c241f53863a818f8631106a25c3d9942efbe5/js/ui/main.js#L204):

```js
// main.js, line #204
keyboard = new Keyboard.KeyboardManager();
```

By the time the `keyboard` variable has been assigned to the instance, a default `Keyboard.Keyboard` class has been created and the function `_setupKeyboard()` has already been called in [`Keyboard._init()`](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/5d1c241f53863a818f8631106a25c3d9942efbe5/js/ui/keyboard.js#L1260), which is much sooner than your extension is loaded.

Since there's no way to easily fix that, your best option is to just re-create the one part of the code you want to run:

```js
const Meta = imports.gi.Meta;
const Main = imports.ui.main;
const Keyboard = imports.ui.keyboard.Keyboard;


const originalSetup = Keyboard.prototype._setupKeyboard;

const modifiedSetup = function () {
    originalSetup.call(this);

    if (!Meta.is_wayland_compositor()) {
        this._connectSignal(this._keyboardController, 'emoji-visible',
            this._onEmojiKeyVisible.bind(this));
    }
        
    this._relayout();
};


function init() {
}

// Your extension's enable function (might be a class method)
function enable() {
    let kbd = Main.keyboard.keyboardActor;

    if (kbd !== null) {
        if (!Meta.is_wayland_compositor()) {
            kbd.__mySignalId = kbd._connectSignal(kbd._keyboardController, 'emoji-visible',
                kbd._onEmojiKeyVisible.bind(kbd));
        }
    }

    Keyboard.prototype._setupKeyboard = modifiedSetup;
}

function disable() {
    let kbd = Main.keyboard.keyboardActor;

    if (kbd !== null && kbd.__mySignalId) {
        kbd.disconnect(kbd.__mySignalId);
        kbd.__mySignalId = 0;
    }

    Keyboard.prototype._setupKeyboard = originalSetup;
}
```

This is not very pretty, but that is often the price of patching private code. I can also not guarantee that the code will do what you want, because I suspect the emoji key is hidden on X11 for a reason.

Comment: I've updated my answer, but as noted I can't guarantee this will actually do what you want.